# Bypass onclick form search value

Tags: forms, input, onclick, radio-button

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/apamvz1r/1/

I have the following code that I would like to eliminate the need for the visitor to click the radio button before searching... Is this possible? I would like to completely eliminate this field or hide it.

```
     <input type="radio" name="RProducts" onclick="frmSearch.Products.value='BB'">
```

If you don't click on the radio input, it doesn't work properly, even if i pre-select it, it still needs to be directly clicked on. Is there a way around this?

```
<form action="http://search1.bestbenefits.com/provsearch.asp" method="post" name="frmSearch" id="frmSearch" target="_blank" onSubmit="return CheckParams()">
     <input type="hidden" name="Products" value="">
     <input type="hidden" name="Title" value="24-7_MedPlan-20140416">
     <input type="radio" name="RProducts" onclick="frmSearch.Products.value='BB'">Search Providers
     <br />Zip Code: <input type="text" size="9" name="Zip" maxlength="5"><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Search for Providers">
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="radio" hidden checked="checked" name="RProducts" onclick="frmSearch.Products.value='BB'">

Comment: I've already tried this. This does not work - hence the onclick requirement.

Comment: Then find out why it doesn't work - because it should.

Comment: That's why I'm here... You have to literally click on the radio for this to work which performs this action - frmSearch.Products.value='BB'

I would like it to automatically click it or bypass the need for it to be clicked...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to automatically physically 'click' an element - I know you can trigger a click event - which handles the javascript event for that triggered element - however <a><input> and a few other elements aren't handled that way.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle is right, I have made an answer and included code there

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<form action="http://search1.bestbenefits.com/provsearch.asp" method="post" name="frmSearch" id="frmSearch" target="_blank" onSubmit="return CheckParams()">
     <input type="hidden" name="Products" value="">
     <input type="hidden" name="Title" value="24-7_MedPlan-20140416">
     <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="RProducts" onclick="frmSearch.Products.value='BB'">Search Providers
     <br />Zip Code: <input type="text" size="9" name="Zip" maxlength="5"><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Search for Providers">
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work - you get the splash screen and then it returns-

Invalid Arguments

Provider search query requires the following parameters:

zip : ZIP Code for nearest providers
products : One or more product codes separated by periods
title : The title to appear on the search page

Comment: You did not specify the values of the zip code or the title. How is this connected to bypassing a click at radio buttons?

Comment: I don't see how you're saying this works when it doesn't. Do you get a list of providers for your zip code? or an error screen???

Comment: It is very simple. When you tell someone that something "works" or something "does not work" you are basically confirming that the behavior is in conform or is not in conform with your expectations. If you do not specify what your expectations actually are, nobody will understand you. When I say it "works", I am saying that the radio button is filled. This is the problem your question addresses, so, when I state it works, I address the problem. You have never specified any expectations regarding title or zip code. We cannot answer a question you do not ask.